# how to show movie problem is also a NP hard Problem

Tags: data-structures, np-hard, polynomial-approximations

I am working on an NP hard problem, here is the problem:

" We need to either watch the movie or speak to friend and hear their recommendations about the movie. We only have t hours. " For this I need to design a polynomial-time algorithm for choosing t/2 recommenders and also I need to prove that it is NP hard problem.

Here, my question is which NP hard problem needs to be chosen to show that the given problem is NP hard. Can I choose subset sum NP hard problem for this.
Please help me.